# How to configure the knife plugin for Chef on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM Instance using GCP

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting this error when trying to configure the knife plugin for Chef in an Ubuntu 14.04 instance on Google Cloud Platform. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
FATAL: Cannot find subcommand for: 'osc_user configure -i'
```

There are 2 VMs - one is the chef-server and the other the chef-workstation, both are the same OS.

Source :- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible-appendix#getting-started-with-chef-on-compute-engine

Chef-server VM IP - https://35.227.106.170/
Chef-workstation VM IP - https://35.231.42.82/

Here is the console log:

```
anjalithomas_mec@chef-workstation:~/.chef$ knife configure -i  # server: https://[server's external IP address]:443,  cookbook_path = ~/chef-repo
Please enter the chef server URL: [https://chef-workstation.c.chef-gcp-195115.internal/organizations/myorg] https://35.227.80.216  
Please enter a name for the new user: [anjalithomas_mec] any  
Please enter the existing admin name: [admin]   
Please enter the location of the existing admin's private key: [/etc/chef-server/admin.pem]   
Overwrite /home/anjalithomas_mec/.chef/credentials?? (Y/N) Y  
Creating initial API user...  
Please enter a password for the new user:   
WARNING: IF YOU ARE USING CHEF SERVER 12+, PLEASE FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTIONS  
UNDER knife user create --help.  
You only passed a single argument to knife user create.  
For backwards compatibility, when only a single argument is passed,
knife user create assumes you want Open Source 11 Server user creation.
knife user create for Open Source 11 Server is being deprecated.  
Open Source 11 Server user commands now live under the knife osc_user namespace.  
For backwards compatibility, we will forward this request to knife osc_user create.  
If you are using an Open Source 11 Server, please use that command to avoid this warning.  
NOTE: Backwards compatibility for Open Source 11 Server in these commands will be removed  
in Chef 15 which will be released April 2019.  
FATAL: Cannot find subcommand for: 'osc_user configure -i'
```

Comment: In one of the earlier questions, it was given create a pem file but making a self signed pem is still not working and the knife client list command does not give the required command -

Comment: Which knife plugin are you using? What is the exact question? Can you please edit the question and give us an explanation so we can help you?

Comment: I am trying to configure the knife - google command based on the instructions given on https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible-appendix#getting-started-with-chef-on-compute-engine,  The point at which the knife configure command is used is where I get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an open issue with no fix yet:

> chef client - error during Knife configure -i #4814
>   https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4814